# Authenticating restricted user to Cloud Files on Rackspace using openstack.net

Tags: .net, openstack, rackspace-cloud

On Rackspace cloud management portal, I created a user that has access to only Cloud Files service and when I login to the portal with this user everything works fine. The account is only given access to the files tab as expected. And I can create/view/delete files from the UI.

But I cannot authenticate this user in my code using openstack.net library. I try the same with my primary user and the authentication works fine in my code. But using the primary users API key in the application is not an option due to security concerns.

```
            var identity =
            new CloudIdentity()
            {
                Username = "username",
                APIKey = "apikey",
            };

            var storage = new CloudFilesProvider(identity);

            storage.CreateObject("sitefiles", inputStream, fileName);
```

I get the exception "The user does not have access to the requested service or region"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I faced the same problem however I provided username, apikey, password but it didn't work !. I figured out that you should specify a region so the user can access it. like :

```
        var identity =
        new CloudIdentity()
        {
            Username = "username",
            APIKey = "apikey",
        };

        var storage = new CloudFilesProvider(identity);

        storage.CreateObject("sitefiles", inputStream, fileName, region: "LON");
```

Try it and it will work.

Comment: Faced same issue today, but it was working fine earlier without specifying region. And weird thing is that i was not able to find any change log by Rackspace.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my observations today, it appears that Username+API Key authentication does not work for users created through the User Management feature. However, for those users you can use Username+Password authentication for API access to features like Cloud Files.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that users created through the UI (i.e. child accounts) do not have the correct `DefaultRegion` set on the `CloudFilesProvider` through their identity. If you were to use Mohamed's example from above:

```
var identity =
new CloudIdentity()
{
    Username = "username",
    APIKey = "apikey",
};

var storage = new CloudFilesProvider(identity);

Console.Write(storage.DefaultRegion); // is always null
```

If you were to do this with a parent account (i.e. the root account), the `DefaultRegion` would be correctly set.

As Mohamed points out, you can only manually set the region in the API call. There is no other workaround for child accounts. Appears to be a bug.